# Build failing for iOS: Flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

Build on iOS fails and showing random error like,

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Can anyone share the solution? Thanks in advance.

NB: It's working on Android well.

Comment: quit the flutter run process and try again